# how to show local html folder in webview

Tags: html, flutter, webview, dart

I want to display a html folder in the webview, which includes CSS and javascript.
Like this folder : [javascript_button](https://filebin.net/rbrtr5dk6vzxqazk/button.zip?t=itaqd57y)

[image]

And this folder should be on the sdcard path of memory rather than in the application assets folder.
I tried various plugins like [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter), [flutter_inappbrowser](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappbrowser) and [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and did not get to the result.
With the following method, I was able to read the index.html only and no other related files were displayed inside the folder.
Please help me to solve this problem.

```js
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String filePath = '/sdcard/Download/button/index.html';
  final flutterWebViewPlugin = FlutterWebviewPlugin();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        "/": (_) => WebviewScaffold(
          url:new Uri.dataFromString(readFileAsync(filePath), mimeType:
               'text/html').toString(),
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("webview"),
          ),
          withJavascript: true,
          supportMultipleWindows: true,
          withLocalUrl: true,
          allowFileURLs: true,
          withLocalStorage: true,
        )
      },
    );
  }
  
  String readFileAsync(String path) {
    String contents = new File('$path').readAsStringSync();
    print(contents);
    return contents;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code using Webview_Flutter plugin in Scaffold:

```
  WebView(
            initialUrl: '',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _webViewController = webViewController;
              _loadHtmlFromAssets();
            },
          ),

// function to load Assets files
//filePath in bellow code for ex.(String filePath = '/assests/files/abc1.html';)


_loadHtmlFromAssets() async {
    String fileHtmlContents = await rootBundle.loadString(filePath);
    _webViewController.loadUrl(Uri.dataFromString(fileHtmlContents,
        mimeType: 'text/html', encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'))
        .toString());
  }
```